# How to clone form fields without their values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to clone following html without persisting the field values?

```
<form method=POST action="/url">
    <div class="form-group" data-answer>
        <div class="pull-left"><label><input type="checkbox" name="answer[1][is_correct]" value="true"> Correct Answer</label></div>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="#" data-remove><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[1][body]" placeholder="Possible answer">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" data-answer>
        <div class="pull-left"><label><input type="checkbox" name="answer[2][is_correct]" value="true"> Correct Answer</label></div>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="#" data-remove><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[2][body]" placeholder="Possible answer">
    </div>

    . . .

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I can see only 3 possible choices here. However, all of them come with major flaws:

1. `.clone()` the `.form-field` normally and reset the field values. 
   **Problem:** resetting all the values one by one is cumbersome and is not a future-proof solution. For example, if more fields are added into the `.form-group`, their values will need to be cleared separately.
2. Include a hidden `.form-group` as a template on the page. 
   **Problem:** as you see, the input fields contain enumerated names like: `answer[1][body]`. It is convenient to clone the last `.form-group` and just increment the value by 1. Cloning the templated `.form-group` will be lacking this flexibility.
3. Read the fields as raw html and transform them into JQuery object 
   **Problem:** this seems to be a clear solution to me, however I couldn't get it working. The code `$.parseHTML($('.form-group').html())` does not return a valid JQuery object, which I need to use `.find()` and other methods on.

What will be an effective and elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: What about using the Solution number 1 and reset is with JavaScript `reset()` function? Like this: `document.getElementById("myForm").reset()`. Newly added fields will also reset using this.

Comment: Why would the values need to be cleared separately or one-by-one? You can get the collection of inputs, and either set their value, reset their checked state, etc. as appropriate, no?

Comment: One potential "gotcha" with `reset()` is that it doesn't reset other form attributes, just the value. May or may not be an issue here, but it trips people up on occasion.

Comment: @DaveNewton What if textarea gets added to the form in the future?

Comment: I use option 2 all the time. You can just save the last id in a variable. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Roy `reset()` does not seem to be working with only cloned `.form-group` content. I don't want to reset the entire form

Comment: Okay. If you don't want to reset the whole form then `reset()` will not work. And neither any of your proposed solution without doing some customization.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia What if? A selector returning all inputs in the form will always include all inputs in the form.

Comment: @Chris When it's nested, possibly arbitrarily deep, it's less straight-forward than with a simple list of top-level elements.

Comment: @DaveNewton If I correctly understood your solution, you are proposing to select all input fields ($('input')?) and clear them. But this will not work (and might become source of bugs) if select, or textarea is added to the form in the future

Comment: @AlexanderLomia You'd clear them by type, obviously.

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand, but shouldn't there be a way to clone the fields with their default values, for god's sake (

Comment: @AlexanderLomia That wouldn't be a clone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
    var t = $("form").clone().appendTo("#clonedForm");
    $(t).find("input[type=checkbox],input[type=text], textarea").removeAttr("checked").val('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to avoid handling each type of field separately, but whatever